# Calculate sum opacity from layers

Tags: css, opacity

I am trying to create an "AJAX-spinner" using CSS animations.

I have two layers with 70% opacity that sometimes overlap. The layers have the same color. When the layers overlap completely I want to replace them with a single layer.

I figured that the two layers overlapping would result in a fully opaque layer, 70 + 70 is 140 after all. But that is not how opacity works apparently. The two layers overlapping is still transparent, what I can't figure out is how transparent.

The only thing I can find how to do is to calculate the resulting color, but that's not what I'm interested in. How can I find the resulting opacity?

```
.layer1,
.layer2 {
    color: orange;
    opacity: .7;
}

.layer3 {
    color: orange;
    opacity: ??;
}
```

#### Update

Fiddle to illustrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/m8zEX/3/

You can see the two orange squares overlapping, and how the color blends with the black square at the back.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS overlapping elements & opacity issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295478/css-overlapping-elements-opacity-issue)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is StackOverflow question addressing this issue [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295478/css-overlapping-elements-opacity-issue)

In your case first div block 70% background light (since opacity is 0.7). Another div which sits on top of that block more 70% background light of remaining visible light.

Thus,

```
Total Opacity = First Opacity + (100 - First Opacity) * Second Opacity
              = 0.7 + (1 - 0.7) * 0.7
              = 0.7 + (0.3) * 0.7
              = 0.7 + 0.21
              = 0.91
```

Thus you should use opacity 0.91 OR 91% for your third div.

Answer (score 1):

`opacity: .7;` means `70%`, if you use `70%` twice, that means `70%` of `70%`. Doing basic math that comes out to `.49` or `49%`.

So applying this in your question, you will have this result:

```
.layer3 {
    color: orange;
    opacity: .49;
}
```

---

Based on your comment, I have set up an example for your issue. From what I see in my demo, it is adding up together, but it is just handling like `opacity: 1;` - please see my demo [right here](http://jsfiddle.net/dV5JV/)

Comment: That makes sense, but I don't apply 70% opacity twice to the same element, but to two different overlapping layers. The result should at least be higher than 70%