# Overlapped elements with opacity and handling the 'hover' on those

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, opacity

This is a Q/A on how to handle the opacity of overlapping elements and make it consistent while hover, with a JS solution.

### Requirement

The requirement is to develop two elements, which are transparent and overlapping, like the two red boxes below. These need to be transparent so that the background contents are visible.

[image]

Now, while hover on any of these elements, the particular element should turn opaque like below.

[image]

Comment: I think the hover part is less relevant here.

Comment: @appleapple - Why do you think so? At least, its part of the requirement :)

Comment: well, if you can do the first, I guess the second is straightforward.

Comment: thanks for this interesting question, anyway.

Comment: @appleapple - True that :) Just saving people's time from deriving the logic.

Comment: would it be ok to decompose those two squares into several small ones, or do you *have* to use ONLY two squares?

Comment: That's totally fine. But I'm unsure whether that's the right approach.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a CSS only solution, which makes it a bit more efficient. Like this for example:

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, #aaa 75%);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
}

#a {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}

#b {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 125px;
  left: 125px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}

#wrapper {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

/* instead of changing the classes,  
you can use selectors like this:*/

#wrapper:hover #a:hover,
#wrapper:hover #b:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 10;
}

#wrapper:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

#wrapper:hover #b,
#wrapper:hover #a {
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id=wrapper>
  <div id="a">
  </div>
  <div id="b">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: css only would be great, do you have an idea on how to make them transparent?

Comment: @Scaramouche not sure what you mean, they are transparent in the example. I've added the background to make it more obvious.

Comment: That's wonderful. I was unaware of those selectors with multiple `hover`.

Comment: With this solution you still have the extra opacity on intersections of other elements, like [here](https://imgur.com/a/NfFTnYx). And it is not JS.

Answer (score 2):

I tried with elements at absolute positions. In this case I'm able to move each of them on top the `wrapper` on mouse enter, then back to their position on mouse leave, via pure JavaScript.

I have expanded the example to 3 elements, where your code shows the artifacts, and added borders to actually see the overlapping.

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/edixon/pen/GdrbWq?editors=1111)

The HTML:

```
<div id=top>
  <div id=wrapper>
    <div class="first" onMouseEnter="hover3b(event)" onMouseLeave="hover3e(event)"></div>
    <div class="second" onMouseEnter="hover3b(event)" onMouseLeave="hover3e(event)"></div>
    <div class="third" onMouseEnter="hover3b(event)" onMouseLeave="hover3e(event)"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, #aaa 75%);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
}

.first, .second, .third {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 3px solid green;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.first { left: 0px; top: 0px; }
.second { left: 80px; top: 80px; }
.third { left: 160px; top: 160px; }
```

The JavaScript:

```
var from = null; // remember where to put back the element
function hover3b(e) {
  var t = e.target;
  from = t.nextElementSibling;
  if (!from)
    from = null;
  document.getElementById("top").appendChild(t);
}
function hover3e(e) {
  document.getElementById("wrapper").insertBefore(e.target, from);
}
```

Comment: This is also a valid solution. Appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

As described in the requirement, the solution starts with creating two elements and probably a wrapper to those.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
</div>
```

Now, we style them to match the design.

```
.first,
.second {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

And the below lines of code for the overlap.

```
.second {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

The problem with [this approach](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/jxOBOX) is that the opacity will not be consistent on the overlapped region and it gets a darker shade.

[image]

Note that this is not a bug with the browsers and the reason for this behaviour is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295478/css-overlapping-elements-opacity-issue).

---

### The right approach

The better way to handle this situation is to avoid making the children elements transparent and instead set 'opacity' in the parent level. And while hover, toggle these opacity levels between the parent and children with JS.

```
$(".first, .second").hover(function() {
  $(".wrapper, .first, .second").not(this).toggleClass("add-opacity");
});
```

Also, the hover on overlapped region would cause flickering due to change in stack order, which can be handled by setting `z-index` to the hovered element.

```
.first:hover,
.second:hover {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/PeojKp)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why did you create a bounty for your question and then answer it yourself?

Comment: To know if there is a better answer.

Comment: "Hope this helps." did it?

Comment: @JorgeZuverza, I'm unsure what you meant.

Comment: @JPeG, FYI, I have answered it last week but the bounty was created yesterday to see if there are better solutions. And there are couple of those posted by other users above.

Answer (score -1):

Here's another approach using [Pointer_events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events)

whenever you hover on an element you disable the `pointer-events` on the other :

```js
$('.first').hover(
  () => { $('.second').css({'pointer-events': 'none'})},
  () => { $('.second').css({'pointer-events': 'auto'})
})

$('.second').hover(
  () => {$('.first').css({'pointer-events': 'none'})},
  () => {$('.first').css({'pointer-events': 'auto'})
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, #aaa 75%);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
}

.wrapper {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.first {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.second {
  width: 99px;
  height: 98px;
  margin-top: -49px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent 50%, rgb(255, 0, 0) 50%), -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 50%, rgb(255, 0, 0) 50%);
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.first:hover,
.second:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first" id="first"></div>
  <div class="second" id="second"></div>
</div>
```

check the [compatibility](https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer) for this as it will work in most browsers except Safari ( as of now ).

Comment: This still don't solve the inconsistent opacity on the overlapped region. Please check my answer on how it is handled.